# How do I set a 4-channel PWM with I2C in Verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, pwm, verilog, i2c, simulation

```
module I2C_Controller(
    inout wire SDA,
    input wire SCL,
    input wire clk,  // Regular clock signal for synthesis
    output wire pwm_out0,
    output wire pwm_out1,
    output wire pwm_out2,
    output wire pwm_out3
);

    // Define states
    parameter IDLE          = 4'b0000;
    parameter START         = 4'b0001;
    parameter READ_ADDRESS  = 4'b0010;
    parameter READ_WRITE    = 4'b0011;
    parameter DATA          = 4'b0100;
    parameter DATA_ACK      = 4'b0101;
    parameter STOP          = 4'b0110;
    parameter ADDRESS_ACK   = 4'b0111;

    reg [3:0] state = IDLE;
    reg [6:0] slaveAddress = 7'b000_1000; // 7-bit I2C Address
    reg [6:0] addressCounter = 0;
    reg [7:0] data = 0;
    reg [7:0] dataCounter = 0;
    reg readWrite = 0;
    reg startDetected = 0;
    reg write_ack = 0;
    reg [1:0] channel_selected; // Channel selection
    reg [7:0] pwm_duty_cycles[3:0]; // Array to hold duty cycle for each PWM channel
    reg [6:0] addr; // Variable to hold address
    
    assign SDA = (write_ack == 1) ? 0 : 1'bz;

    // PWM generator instances
    pwm_generator pwm_gen0(.clk(clk), .duty_cycle(pwm_duty_cycles[0]), .pwm_signal(pwm_out0));
    pwm_generator pwm_gen1(.clk(clk), .duty_cycle(pwm_duty_cycles[1]), .pwm_signal(pwm_out1));
    pwm_generator pwm_gen2(.clk(clk), .duty_cycle(pwm_duty_cycles[2]), .pwm_signal(pwm_out2));
    pwm_generator pwm_gen3(.clk(clk), .duty_cycle(pwm_duty_cycles[3]), .pwm_signal(pwm_out3));

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (startDetected) begin
            case (state)
                READ_ADDRESS: begin
                    if (addressCounter < 7) begin
                        addressCounter <= addressCounter + 1;
                        if (addressCounter == 6) begin
                            channel_selected <= addr[1:0]; // Assuming LSBs of address are for channel selection
                            state <= READ_WRITE;
                        end
                    end
                    addr[addressCounter] <= SDA;
                    $display("Time: %t, State: READ_ADDRESS, Address Bit: %b", $time, SDA);
                end
                READ_WRITE: begin
                    readWrite <= SDA;
                    state <= ADDRESS_ACK;
                    $display("Time: %t, State: READ_WRITE, R/W Bit: %b", $time, SDA);
                end
                ADDRESS_ACK: begin
                    write_ack <= 1;
                    state <= DATA;
                    $display("Time: %t, State: ADDRESS_ACK, Sending ACK", $time);
                end
                DATA: begin
                    if (dataCounter < 8) begin
                        data[dataCounter] <= SDA;
                        dataCounter <= dataCounter + 1;
                    end else begin
                        // Update PWM duty cycle based on received data
                        pwm_duty_cycles[channel_selected] <= data;
                        state <= DATA_ACK;
                        write_ack <= 1;
                        $display("PWM updated!!!");
                    end
                    $display("Time: %t, State: DATA, Data Bit: %b", $time, SDA);
                end
                DATA_ACK: begin
                    write_ack <= 0;
                    state <= STOP;
                    $display("Time: %t, State: DATA_ACK, Updating PWM duty cycle: %d", $time, data);
                end
                STOP: begin
                    startDetected <= 0;
                    state <= IDLE;
                    $display("Time: %t, State: STOP, Stop Condition Detected", $time);
                end
            endcase
        end else begin
            if (!SDA && SCL) begin
                // Start condition detected
                startDetected <= 1;
                state <= READ_ADDRESS;
                addressCounter <= 0;
                dataCounter <= 0;
            end else if (SDA && !SCL) begin
                // Stop condition detected
                startDetected <= 0;
                state <= IDLE;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule

// PWM Generator Module
module pwm_generator(
    input wire clk,
    input wire [7:0] duty_cycle,
    output reg pwm_signal
);

    reg [7:0] counter = 0;
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
        pwm_signal <= (counter < duty_cycle) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
        
    end
endmodule

module tb_i2c_controller;

    // Inputs
    reg clk = 0;
    reg sda_tb = 1; // SDA high by default
    reg scl_tb = 1; // SCL high by default

    // Outputs
    assign SDA = sda_tb;
    assign SCL = scl_tb;
    wire pwm_out0, pwm_out1, pwm_out2, pwm_out3;
    parameter slave_address = 7'b000_1000;
    
     initial begin
        forever #5 clk = ~clk;  // Generate a clock with a period of 10 ns
    end
    // Generate SCL clock with the desired frequency for I2C
    // This example uses a 100kHz I2C clock
    initial begin
        forever #(5000) scl_tb = ~scl_tb; // 100kHz Clock
    end
    
    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    I2C_Controller UUT (
        .SDA(SDA),
        .SCL(SCL),
        .clk(clk),
        .pwm_out0(pwm_out0),
        .pwm_out1(pwm_out1),
        .pwm_out2(pwm_out2),
        .pwm_out3(pwm_out3)
    );

    // Main test sequence
    initial begin
        $display("Starting Testbench...");

        // Initialize testbench signals
        
        i2c_start();

        // Test different PWM values for each channel
        send_pwm_value(0, 8'b00000000); // Channel 0, PWM = 0
        send_pwm_value(1, 8'b00110010); // Channel 1, PWM = 50
        send_pwm_value(2, 8'b01100100); // Channel 2, PWM = 100
        send_pwm_value(3, 8'b11111111); // Channel 3, PWM = 255

        // Finish simulation
        #1000;
        i2c_stop();
        $display("Testbench Completed.");
        $finish;
    end

    // I2C start condition
    task i2c_start;
    begin
        @(posedge clk);
        sda_tb = 0; // SDA goes low while SCL is high
        @(posedge clk);
    end
    endtask

    // I2C stop condition
    task i2c_stop;
    begin
        @(posedge clk);
        scl_tb = 1; // Ensure SCL is high before SDA goes high
        sda_tb = 1; // SDA goes high to mark stop condition
        @(posedge clk);
    end
    endtask

    // Send a byte of data
    task i2c_send_byte;
        input [7:0] byte;
        integer i;
    begin
        for (i = 7; i >= 0; i = i - 1) begin
            @(posedge clk);
            sda_tb = byte[i]; // Setup data while SCL is low
            @(posedge clk);
        end
        // Add code to check for ACK from the slave
        // ...
    end
    endtask

    // Task to send PWM value to a specific channel
    task send_pwm_value;
        input [1:0] channel;
        input [7:0] pwm_value;
    begin
        i2c_start();
        i2c_send_byte({slave_address, 0}); // Slave address with write bit
        i2c_send_byte({channel, pwm_value}); // PWM value with channel info
        i2c_stop();
        $display("Time: %t, Channel: %d, Sent PWM Value: %d", $time, channel, pwm_value);
    end
    endtask


    // Task to read back and display PWM output for a specific channel
    task readback_pwm;
        input [1:0] channel;
        begin
            case (channel)
                0: $display("Time: %t, Channel 0 PWM Output: %b", $time, pwm_out0);
                1: $display("Time: %t, Channel 1 PWM Output: %b", $time, pwm_out1);
                2: $display("Time: %t, Channel 2 PWM Output: %b", $time, pwm_out2);
                3: $display("Time: %t, Channel 3 PWM Output: %b", $time, pwm_out3);
                default: $display("Time: %t, Invalid Channel", $time);
            endcase
        end
    endtask

endmodule
```

I have tried up to three different code variations and tried many things, but I still can not get to set the PWM using the I2C.

I'm thinking it can be either the PWM module, the I2C signaling in the testbench or a timing issue.  If someone can point me in the right direction, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your Verilog code with the Synopsys VCS simulator, I get a warning message:

```
Warning-[CWUC] Concatenations with unsized constants
"0"
  An unsized constant '0' is used in the concatenation. The unsized constant 
  will be used as a 32-bit constant.
```

It points to this line of code in the testbench module:

```
    i2c_send_byte({slave_address, 0}); // Slave address with write bit
```

The `i2c_send_byte` task accepts an 8-bit value.  You think you are passing it an 8-bit value where the 7 MSBs are the 7-bit `slave_address` and the LSB is 0, but you are really passing 8 bits of 0.  The 7-bit `slave_address` is ignored.

Change the line as follows to get rid of the warning:

```
    i2c_send_byte({slave_address, 1'b0}); // Slave address with write bit
```

There is also a bit-width issue for the following line:

```
    i2c_send_byte({channel, pwm_value}); // PWM value with channel info
```

Since `channel` is 2 bits, and `pwm_value` is 8 bits, and the task only accepts 8 bits, `channel` is ignored.

When I look at waveforms for your simulation, I see that `SCL` never toggles.  The simulation is stopped by `$finish` in the testbench before SCL goes low.  You should run the simulation for a longer duration.

---

As an aside, you should not create a signal named `byte` in the `i2c_send_byte` task because it is a reserved keyword added in the SystemVerilog extension to the language.