# I2C slave PWM Verilog problems

Tags: digital-logic, pwm, verilog, i2c, vivado

I have been trying to get this I2C slave controller to work and send PWM signals, but I still can not drive the PWM. I think that it is an issue with the testbench on maybe how the slave controller is receiving and selecting channels. If someone can tell me how to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated.   I did have a previous post, but even after those changes and a couple more, it still doesn't work.

Previous post: [How do I set a 4-channel PWM with I2C in Verilog?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691194/how-do-i-set-a-4-channel-pwm-with-i2c-in-verilog)

```
module I2C_Controller(
    inout wire SDA,
    input wire SCL,
    input wire clk,  // Regular clock signal for synthesis
    output wire pwm_out0,
    output wire pwm_out1,
    output wire pwm_out2,
    output wire pwm_out3
);

    // Define states
    parameter IDLE          = 4'b0000;
    parameter START         = 4'b0001;
    parameter READ_ADDRESS  = 4'b0010;
    parameter READ_WRITE    = 4'b0011;
    parameter DATA          = 4'b0100;
    parameter DATA_ACK      = 4'b0101;
    parameter STOP          = 4'b0110;
    parameter ADDRESS_ACK   = 4'b0111;

    reg [3:0] state = IDLE;
    reg [6:0] slaveAddress = 7'b000_1000; // 7-bit I2C Address
    reg [6:0] addressCounter = 0;
    reg [7:0] data = 0;
    reg [7:0] dataCounter = 0;
    reg readWrite = 0;
    reg startDetected = 0;
    reg write_ack = 0;
    reg [1:0] channel; // Channel selection
    reg [7:0] pwm_value; // PWM duty cycle value
    reg [1:0] byteCounter = 0; // Counter for bytes received after address
    reg [7:0] pwm_duty_cycles[3:0]; // Array to hold duty cycle for each PWM channel

    // Initialize the duty cycles to a known state
    initial begin
        pwm_duty_cycles[0] = 8'd0;
        pwm_duty_cycles[1] = 8'd0;
        pwm_duty_cycles[2] = 8'd0;
        pwm_duty_cycles[3] = 8'd0;
    end

    assign SDA = (write_ack == 1) ? 0 : 1'bz;

    // PWM generator instances
    pwm_generator pwm_gen0(.clk(clk), .duty_cycle(pwm_duty_cycles[0]), .pwm_signal(pwm_out0));
    pwm_generator pwm_gen1(.clk(clk), .duty_cycle(pwm_duty_cycles[1]), .pwm_signal(pwm_out1));
    pwm_generator pwm_gen2(.clk(clk), .duty_cycle(pwm_duty_cycles[2]), .pwm_signal(pwm_out2));
    pwm_generator pwm_gen3(.clk(clk), .duty_cycle(pwm_duty_cycles[3]), .pwm_signal(pwm_out3));

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (startDetected) begin
            case (state)
                READ_ADDRESS: begin
                    if (addressCounter < 7) begin
                        addressCounter <= addressCounter + 1;
                        slaveAddress[addressCounter] <= SDA;
                        $display("Time: %t, State: READ_ADDRESS, Address Bit: %b", $time, SDA);
                    end else begin
                        state <= READ_WRITE;
                    end
                end
                READ_WRITE: begin
                    readWrite <= SDA;
                    state <= ADDRESS_ACK;
                    $display("Time: %t, State: READ_WRITE, R/W Bit: %b", $time, SDA);
                end
                ADDRESS_ACK: begin
                    write_ack <= 1;
                    state <= DATA;
                    $display("Time: %t, State: ADDRESS_ACK, Sending ACK", $time);
                end
                DATA: begin
                    if (dataCounter < 8) begin
                        data[dataCounter] <= SDA;
                        dataCounter <= dataCounter + 1;
                    end else begin
                        if (byteCounter == 0) begin
                            channel <= data[1:0]; // Use only 2 bits for channel indexing
                            byteCounter <= byteCounter + 1;
                        end else if (byteCounter == 1) begin
                            pwm_value <= data;
                            pwm_duty_cycles[channel] <= pwm_value;
                            byteCounter <= 0;
                            state <= DATA_ACK;
                            write_ack <= 1;
                            $display("PWM Channel %d updated: Duty Cycle = %d", channel, pwm_value);
                        end
                        dataCounter <= 0;
                    end
                    $display("Time: %t, State: DATA, Data Bit: %b", $time, SDA);
                end
                DATA_ACK: begin
                    write_ack <= 0;
                    state <= STOP;
                    $display("Time: %t, State: DATA_ACK, Updating PWM duty cycle: %d", $time, data);
                end
                STOP: begin
                    startDetected <= 0;
                    state <= IDLE;
                    $display("Time: %t, State: STOP, Stop Condition Detected", $time);
                end
            endcase
        end else begin
            if (!SDA && SCL) begin
                // Start condition detected
                startDetected <= 1;
                state <= READ_ADDRESS;
                addressCounter <= 0;
                dataCounter <= 0;
            end else if (SDA && !SCL) begin
                // Stop condition detected
                startDetected <= 0;
                state <= IDLE;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule

// PWM Generator Module
module pwm_generator(
    input wire clk,
    input wire [7:0] duty_cycle,
    output reg pwm_signal
);

    reg [7:0] counter = 0;
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
        pwm_signal <= (counter < duty_cycle) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
    end
endmodule
```

Testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module tb_i2c_controller;
    // Inputs
    reg clk = 0;
    reg sda_drive = 1; // Control signal for driving SDA
    reg sda_tb = 1; // SDA high by default
    reg scl_tb = 1; // SCL high by default

    // Outputs
    wire pwm_out0, pwm_out1, pwm_out2, pwm_out3;
    wire SDA, SCL;

    // Tri-state buffer for SDA line
    assign SDA = (sda_drive) ? sda_tb : 1'bz;

    parameter slave_address = 7'b000_1000;
    
    // Generate clock signal
    initial begin
        forever #5 clk = ~clk;  // Generate a clock with a period of 10 ns
    end

    // Generate SCL clock with the desired frequency for I2C
    initial begin
        forever #(5000) scl_tb = ~scl_tb; // 100kHz Clock
    end
    
    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    I2C_Controller UUT (
        .SDA(SDA),
        .SCL(SCL),
        .clk(clk),
        .pwm_out0(pwm_out0),
        .pwm_out1(pwm_out1),
        .pwm_out2(pwm_out2),
        .pwm_out3(pwm_out3)
    );

    // Main test sequence
    initial begin
        $display("Starting Testbench...");

        // Initialize testbench signals
        sda_drive = 0; // Release SDA line initially
        i2c_start();
        sda_drive = 1; // Take control of SDA line

        // Test different PWM values for each channel
        send_pwm_value(0, 8'b00000000); // Channel 0, PWM = 0
        send_pwm_value(1, 8'b00110010); // Channel 1, PWM = 50
        send_pwm_value(2, 8'b01100100); // Channel 2, PWM = 100
        send_pwm_value(3, 8'b11111111); // Channel 3, PWM = 255

        // Finish simulation
        #1000;
        i2c_stop();
        $display("Testbench Completed.");
        $finish;
    end

    // I2C start condition
    task i2c_start;
    begin
        @(posedge clk);
        sda_tb = 0; // SDA goes low while SCL is high
        @(posedge clk);
    end
    endtask

    // I2C stop condition
    task i2c_stop;
    begin
        @(posedge clk);
        scl_tb = 1; // Ensure SCL is high before SDA goes high
        sda_tb = 1; // SDA goes high to mark stop condition
        @(posedge clk);
    end
    endtask

    // Send a byte of data
    task i2c_send_data;
        input [7:0] byte;
        integer i;
    begin
        for (i = 7; i >= 0; i = i - 1) begin
            scl_tb = 0; // SCL low before changing SDA
            @(posedge clk);
            sda_tb = byte[i]; // Setup data while SCL is low
            @(posedge clk);
            scl_tb = 1; // SCL high to clock in the data
            @(posedge clk);
        end
        // ACK handling
        @(posedge clk);
        scl_tb = 0; // SCL low to end the bit transmission
        sda_drive = 0; // Release SDA line for slave to pull low for ACK
        @(posedge clk);
        scl_tb = 1; // SCL high to clock in ACK
        @(posedge clk);
        scl_tb = 0; // SCL low after ACK
        @(posedge clk);
        sda_drive = 1; // Take control of SDA line again
    end
    endtask

    // Task to send PWM value to a specific channel
    task send_pwm_value;
        input [1:0] channel;
        input [7:0] pwm_value;
    begin
        i2c_start();
        sda_drive = 1; // Take control of SDA line
        i2c_send_data({slave_address, 1'b0}); // Slave address with write bit

        i2c_send_data({channel, 6'b000000}); // Send channel number
        i2c_send_data(pwm_value); // Send PWM value

        i2c_stop();
        $display("Time: %t, Channel: %d, Sent PWM Value: %d", $time, channel, pwm_value);
    end
    endtask

    // Task to read back and display PWM output for a specific channel
    task readback_pwm;
        input [1:0] channel;
        begin
            case (channel)
                0: $display("Time: %t, Channel 0 PWM Output: %b", $time, pwm_out0);
                1: $display("Time: %t, Channel 1 PWM Output: %b", $time, pwm_out1);
                2: $display("Time: %t, Channel 2 PWM Output: %b", $time, pwm_out2);
                3: $display("Time: %t, Channel 3 PWM Output: %b", $time, pwm_out3);
                default: $display("Time: %t, Invalid Channel", $time);
            endcase
        end
    endtask

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the testbench code.  You did not drive the `SCL` input.  Change:

```
    .SCL(SCL),
```

to:

```
    .SCL(scl_tb),
```

This was obvious to me when I viewed waveforms of the simulation.  It is usually insufficient to rely on display statements when debugging.  The `SCL` input of `UUT` did not toggle and had the value `z` (high-impedance).

Making the above change allows the serial clock signal to toggle in the design.

---

As an aside, you should not create a signal named `byte` in the `i2c_send_byte` task because it is a reserved keyword added in the SystemVerilog extension to the language.  Rename it as something like `byte_data`.

Comment: Thank you, it is still not working. I can't seem to get it to work I have had 4 different codes. I'm about to give up on it.

Comment: @LuisGarza: You're welcome.  Since you are a new user: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)  You should Accept this answer since it solves the immediate problem.  I encourage you to keep working at it with a different approach.  Start with fewer lines of code, and make sure it simulates properly before adding more code.  As you encounter new problems, you should  open a new question with your new code.  Also, upvoting answers is nice, too.

Comment: I appreciate it, I do want to comment for anyone who might want to use this code things to take into consideration are that i2c is not working, and when it would the slave controller would need to be modified to properly take more than one byte to select the proper channel, along with any other issues.